# How to render picture as 4 mega pixels?

Tags: rendering

I wanna create Shutterstock friendly pictures but it has to be 4 megapixels. How do I render my picture as 4 MP so that I can upload it on Shutterstock?

Comment: you don't know where to set render resolution, you don't know what resolution to choose so it is 4MP or both?

Comment: google reports 4MP as 2592x1520 https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=4mp+resolution+pixels

Answer (score 1):

one megapixel is one million pixels. Make the area of your picture equal 4 million pixels

The dimension for a 4:3 ratio would be 2309 x 1732 with 4 megapixels, so set width to 2309 and height 1732
if you dont know how to set dimensions use the amazing google recource... thats how i answered you... with https://www.scantips.com/mpixels.html

Comment: This is exactly what I said earlier, but without any attempt of makeup

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control your proportions and get the minimum amount of pixel you legally can:

First determine the right proportions for your composition:

1. adjust the camera position (<kbd>G</kbd>) and the *Focal length* from the Camera settings
   [image]
2. in the *Dimensions* panel of the Render tab, keep Y fixed to 1000 and adjust X to obtain the most suitable proportions
   [image]
   (make sure to have the percentage at 100% before the final render)

Now you need to scale up your measures to get at least 4 million pixels (4 *mega* pixels) or, to be extra sure, 4'194'304 pixels (as "mega" usually indicates 2<sup>20</sup> = 1'048'576 in digital contexts).

Take note of the X value that you entered (`oldx`)

Calculate:

- 64.8 * **√**(`oldx`), round it, and type it as your new "X" value
- 64800 / **√**(`oldx`), round it, and type it as your new "Y" value

---

If you are happy with one of many possible canned proportions, instead of doing all the calculations, just use:

```
    1:1   →  2048 x 2048
    4:3   →  2365 x 1774
   16:9   →  2731 x 1536
    3:2   →  2508 x 1672
   16:10  →  2591 x 1619
```

Answer (score 0):

One megapixel is one milion pixels. To calculate your image's pixel amount, just multiply the length with width. You can also use the [Megapixel Calculator](https://toolstud.io/photo/megapixel.php).

Example: To get at least a 4 megapixel image is, using common photography ratio aspect, your image needs the dimensions of 2560x1920 pixels (= 4 915 200 pixels).

You can set your image dimensions in the right toolbar under Render > Dimensions:
[image: Dimensions]

Comment: thousand would be kilo, mega is times million

Comment: jspr has amended the answer. However, I don't believe that a trivial mistake (writing thousands instead of million), especially if the rest of the answer clearly assumes the right order of magnitude, justifies that many downvotes. Also, a trivial mistake could be fixed by users with enough reputation, if the intent of the original answer is clear.